# how to lower CPU usage in Ableton Live 8 in Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: ableton, ableton-live

While running Ableton Live 8 after a project gets to a certain size, the audio starts to get a bit choppy and distorted. My levels are fine and is not the cause of the lag and chop.

I have samples set to 1024 and the high quality button selected which I need to hear the sound. I always lower these when I'm recording audio with my mic but I need to have these turned up to be able to mix and master songs.

Anything I can do to lower the CPU usage? It sucks because I can't even use my iZotope Ozone plug-ins because of their CPU usage and they are AMAZING plug-ins that I would love to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bouncing certain tracks track to audio could be an option (those that have a heavy effect chain). What I usually do in my DAW (StudioOne) when things start to go a bit funky is bounce the whole track with effects to audio and use that. This drastically reduces CPU usage as no effects are running in realtime. A great feature in S1 is to reverse this process if you want to make any edits as it saves the configuration of the effect chain to re-apply it. Maybe check to see if Ableton can do this? I am almost certain you can bounce to audio but not sure on the reverse process.

Comment: Ableton has a "Freeze" option which I started using that sounds similar to this. Only downside to it is that it lowers the quality of the audio and requires the track to be unfrozen when exporting to regain its quality. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum Do you have a reference to describe how it lowers audio quality? I was under the impression that this wasn't the case.